# Defining abilities with block for action index with CanCan and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, indexing, block, cancan

I need to add a filter on users. A user can see other users only if the user belongs to same branch. One user can belong to multiple branches.

I am defining ability with the blocks below. But after referring to documentation and facing an error I got to know that the `index` method doesn't fit well with defining the ability with block.

```
#This code is part of initialisation method of ability.rb

can :index, User do |curr_user|
    #check if user belongs to same branch
    !curr_user.branch_ids.index(branch_id).nil?
end
```

Here is index method of users controller

```
def index
    authorize! :index, User

    @users = User.where(params[:user]).accessible_by(current_ability, :index)

    renders :obj =>@users
end
```

What is some alternative to define abilities to implement this logic in place of defining abilities with blocks?

Answer (score 1):

`accessible_by` is like a `where` for AR...

You should use a hash of conditions rather than a block to define your ability
see [Defining-Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

Something like ...

```
def initialize(user)
 conditions = branch_id: user.branch_id
 can :read, User, conditions
end
```

I suggest you first spike correct `conditions` in irb console

```
user = User.first
User.where(branch_id: user.branch_id)
```

Then you might want a test